# Building a polygon using COGO/traverse in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, polygon-creation, cogo, metes-and-bounds, modify-features

I have a legal survey and I am trying to digitize a polygon boundary using the metes and bounds. In ArcMap, I would just edit an existing polygon layer using Traverse. In Pro, the "Modify Features" window is only allowing me to select line features from my table of contents, it doesn't seem to recognize any of my polygon layers.

I was able to enter all the metes and bounds and create the boundary with a line layer, but I still need to convert that into a polygon.

The documentation for the Traverse tool on Esri's site says "A traverse can be entered to create a series of line features or a single polygon feature. When entering a traverse, a line feature layer or a polygon feature layer can be used to create the traverse."

Is there some kind of setting that I am missing to allow the Traverse tool to "see" my polygon layers? I am new to Pro.